# Shoud i use slots in other methods

Tags: qt, signals-slots

Is it normal to use slots in other methods? Like here i use releaseIncrement() in Increment() to avoid code duplication:

```
#include "counter1.h"
#include <iostream>

Counter1::Counter1(int startValue)
{
    m_count = startValue;
}

int Counter1::getValue()
{
    return m_count;
}

int Counter1::Increment()
{
    std::cout <<"In class: " <<this <<" method Increment() was called" <<std::endl;
    releaseIncrement(); // I used slot here to avoid code duplicate
    emit wasIncremented();
    return m_count;
}

int Counter1::Decrement()
{
    std::cout <<"In class: " <<this <<" method Increment() was called" <<std::endl;
    releaseDecrement(); // I used slot here to avoid code duplicate
    emit wasDecremented();
    return m_count;
}

void Counter1::releaseIncrement()
{
    m_count++;
    std::cout <<"In class: " <<this << " m_count was incremented by releaseIncrement() methos. Now m_count is: " <<m_count <<std::endl;
}

void Counter1::releaseDecrement()
{
    m_count--;
    std::cout <<"In class: " <<this << " m_count was decremented by releaseDecrement() methos. Now m_count is: " <<m_count <<std::endl;
}
```

It works and works correct, but i feel like I am doing something bad, like it is bad practice. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: Depending on the situation I would use emit

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether you can use slot functions as ordinary functions, the answer is yes - there's nothing special about slots. You can use them anywhere.